# reactjs - anchor tag link

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to output these lines of codes into something like

```
<a href="http://">SOMETHING</a>
```

[image]

**BASE_URL** as [image]

When I run this code, I get this output in the browser:
[image]

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, you just need to lose the quotes:

```
<a href={BASE_URL}>
```

You can play with the JSX compiler at [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/repl/)  to get a slightly better idea of what JS it compiles into.

Answer (score 2):

Also, instead of returning an object, you can use the key attribute

```
return <ul className="nav" key="list"> ... </ul>;
```